# How do I convert this LINQ query to lambda query?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How do I convert this LINQ query to lambda query?

```
public List<Tuple<Klasa2,Klasa2>>CompareLists(List<Klasa2>list1,List<Klasa2>list2)
{
    var pary=
        from l1 in list1
        from l2 in list2
        where l1.tytul.Length<l2.tytul.Length
        select new Tuple<Klasa2,Klasa2>(l1,l2);
    return pary.ToList();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "convert this LINQ query to lambda"?

Comment: FYI the correct phrasing here would be "Convert Linq query syntax to Linq method syntax"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public List<Tuple<Klasa2, Klasa2>> CompareLists(List<Klasa2> list1, List<Klasa2> list2)
{
    var pary =
        list1.SelectMany(l1 => list2, (l1, l2) => new {l1, l2})
            .Where(@t => @t.l1.tytul.Length < @t.l2.tytul.Length)
            .Select(@t => new Tuple<Klasa2, Klasa2>(@t.l1, @t.l2));
    return pary.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting a `@` before the `t`? It isn't a reserved word.

Comment: No, it is not reserved. And I didn't ... ReSharper did ... :)

Comment: Probably slightly better to have the `SelectMany` create the `Tuple` then the `Select` wouldn't even be needed.